# dockpanel alternatives

Tags: c#, wpf

I have read that I can't have my dockpanel scroll so im looking for alternatives

I want to have a lot of slider controls(unknown number) left to right in a panel of some sort that can scroll so I can view all the sliders.  I tried with dock panel but of course that didn't work.  What can I do to make the dockpanel work or what do I replace dockpanel with(the replacement would need to support children)?

Thanks!

EDIT:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5a4u.png

here is the idea but it needs to scroll horizontally

David Brunelle Does work but its not quite what I want.  Id like the scroll bar to be on the top of the control and not attached to the bottom of the window.

Comment: I think I understand, but could you draw some picture of what you want?

Comment: Edit is up with a pic of my failed idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, but you can use a panel within a ScrollViewer

Something like this :

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

      <StackPanel  Margin="2,2,2,2">
      ...
      </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This will allow for vertical scrolling. You could do the same for horizontal scrolling. I do not know if this would work with a docking panel, but I know it does with a stack panel.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is close It adds a scroll bar at the bottom of the window.  I need the scroll bar to only scroll the sliders not the whole window.(rep'ed either way since this works)

Comment: Ok this doesn't scroll the whole window but i would rather have the scroll bar at the top of the control

Comment: If you want the scroll bars are the top, then you would need to edit the template of the ScollViewer and put it on top instead (unless that is, that the scrollviewer has a property to put it on top instead of bottom). This is not a really easy feat but if you have time, luck, and a whole lot of patience, you might be able to pull it off.

Comment: Just for the record, why is that ? Did you actually find the property or did you modify the template ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `ListBox` as it will handle the scrolling part for you, then  you can set the `ItemTemplate` (if you want) and you can use data binding (using an `ObservableCollection` or a `DataView`